# Designing a query that selects records based on a keyword in a combo box

Tags: ms-access

I have records with more than one word that classifies it in the dat base ie:Lubricant- SJG Lubricant Lockhole Sherlock 100ml. in the combo box I list the item as "Lubricant" in a column called "material. All records has this classification, for example "Tools"- then the description.My combo box has a list of materials ie. tools,screws,Fixtures etc the mterial field has the keyword first then a description I need to filter the records based on the keyword in the description.ex. Light Fixtures,Lubricant,Lumber,Nails,Paint, etc.Pipe

I need to filter the records based on the keyword in the description which is the same word in the combo box.ex. Light Fixtures,Lubricant,Lumber,Nails,Paint, etc.Pipe

I created a query

```
[Forms]![TblPurchases]![CboMaterial]
```

I'm not sur hqw to structure the query to lookatthe materials column and filter the records base on the combobox keyword. I am exspecting that if i select "cement" formcombo box I should get a record such as 
Cement - Portland Cement 90lb. bag(this is the "Materials" column's record)

Comment: basically I want to include wildcards in the combo box query

Answer (score 0):

What you are going to want to do, is go into the query designer, and design view. Then in the criteria field in column that you want sort by add:

`LIKE [FORMS]![MAIN_FORM].InputBox & "*"`

This *should* return all results where they start with the text in the input box.

More information on the access Like operator can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931). More information on the SQL LIKE operator can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).

Comment: Eli, Thank you so much for the help. Like I said I'm very green in access and try to resolve issues on my own in order to learn, however there are times I hit walls and your assistance is greatly appreciated as to all others in the community that have in the past rendered their options and advice. /thank you once again.

Comment: Sorry again I got the query working fine but the datasheet shows no records, although my record count in the text box shows the correct number of records the datasheet remains blank, my VBA statement is correct I assume:     task2 = "select * from TblPurchases order by [Material] "
        Me.Filter = "[Material] = '" & Me.CboMaterial & "'"
        Me.TxtTotal = Format(DCount("Material", "TblPurchasesMaterials"), "0")

Comment: So you are setting the form's recordset to the records set from that query? Once you do that make sure to Me.Refresh. Though if that doesn't work you may need to do: Me.SUBFORMNAME.Requery